# Laravel from localhost to server issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I've got a working Laravel website on my localhost, which works fine. I'm trying to move this website to my server (LAMP).

When I send this, I change the htaccess and the database, but I've a got an error message:
`Class 'Ollieread\Multiauth\MultiAuthServiceProvider' not found`

This class is an extern package from github which I installed with composer, and I didn't have any trouble on my localhost, but now on my server I've got this annoying error.

Anyone got any solution or kind of help?

cheers !

Update: service not seervice

Comment: `Seervice` is that verbatim?

Comment: You have typo - it should be  Seeervice - take a look at Laravel source. But anyway gently delete your first post on SO because  it is a ball of mud, and may be  voted down.

Comment: Did you run *composer install* on your server?

Comment: No i didn't do _composer install_ on the server, how can I do this? in local i use 'windows cmd' but on the server I have no clue..

Comment: Run composer install on the server and don't copy the vendor directory there. If you don't have access to composer on server you should change the paths on the vendor dir or create a lib dir and more everything in there and rewrite the autoloader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glad to see people enjoying the package that I wrote.

The class you're looking for is located in `vendor/ollieread/multiauth/src/Ollieread/multiauth`, if you take a look at the namespace deceleration at the top of the files, I clearly define the namespace as `Ollieread\Multiauth` and the composer.json file for my package maps that namespace to the `ollieread/multiauth/src` directory.

I'd say that it sounds like it's been installed in a strange way, or the composer autoload file isn't being generated.

You can install composer on your server quite simply by downloading the composer.phar file, which you can find information about at https://getcomposer.org/download/. Once you have this installed, from the root directory of your laravel installation you can run the command `php /path/to/composer.phar update` or alternatively switch update out for install, and everything should be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution! the problem didn't come from me, but from this package Ollieread... The explanation is the folder's name in vendor was Ollieread, and when i put it in lowercase it works fine!

If it helps someone, anyway i will send an email to this famous ollie read ^^